# Где продавать права на интеллектуальную собственность(ПО)?

Tags: лицензирование, авторские-права

Допустим я разработал программное обеспечение и хочу продать права на него кому-нибудь. То есть продать все исходные коды, базу данных и прочие компоненты. Это можно сделать на авито, но наверное должны быть какие-то специализированные площадки для таких задач, в России я таких не могу найти.

Где мне продавать права на свое ПО

а) В России

б) За границей
???

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Я как-то не очень вижу смысл в существовании подобных площадок... Зачем это потенциальным покупателям?